# How to size The DOL Motor Starter knowing that the motor is a part winding start motor

Tags: current, induction-motor, contactor

I have a BITZER compressor type 4GE-23Y-40P, with a part winding start option of the motor

[image]

Nennspannung = nominal voltage = 380-420

Frequ = frequency = 50

Betr. strom = maximal operating current = 43.9

Anlaufstrom = starting current (A(Y) with the first winding, A(YY) second winding) = [A(Y)=97, A(YY)=158]

I am confused about what current should I consider in the sizing of the compressor starter parts (contactor, fuse, circuit breaker, thermal overload relay)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The sparkies over on the [DIY SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) would probably have a good answer for this.

Comment: Sparkies hehehe....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motor Part Winding starting schemes result in a 60-40 split, so the Start winding is 60% of the current, the Run winding adds the other 40%. Those numbers actually track the values on the nameplate.

When you size contactors, you size them based on the Full Load Amps, in this case the "Betr. strom" of 43.9A; the starting current surge is assumed in any motor contactor design rating.

So you could (in theory) use a contactor rated for 28A on the Start and 17.6 for Run. But most people just get a pair of matching contactors for PW starting. So if you used a pair of contactors rated for 15kW 400V motors AC-3, you are good to go.